# FedoraServer ssh traffic on ipv6 blocked

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, fedora, ipv6

I have my domain setup for ipv6 as well as ipv4. For accessing the https site it all works well.

But when trying to connect to ssh via ipv6 it does not work. You can see in the log below, my ssh client tries ipv6 first and then switches to ipv4.

```
OpenSSH_9.2p1, OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/asd/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/asd/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for 8wu.de
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to url.de [2fe4:4000:66:abc::1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 2fe4:4000:66:abc::1 port 22: No route to host
debug1: Connecting to url.de [89.34.41.52] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
```

But according to lsof the port is opened on my server. When trying to connect to ::1 I also get a response, so the sshd service seems to be working correctly.

```
sudo lsof -l | egrep 'LISTEN' | egrep ssh
sshd       43354                         0    3u     IPv6             179515       0t0        TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd       43354                         0    4u     IPv4             179517       0t0        TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
```

If I nmap my server the port is closed (as expected by sshs output)

```
nmap -p22 -6 -Pn url.de                                   
Starting Nmap 7.93 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-03-05 18:15 CET
Nmap scan report for url.de (2fe4:4000:66:abc::1)
Host is up.
Other addresses for url.de (not scanned): 89.34.41.52

PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.16 seconds
```

I'm using firewalld on my server, but I haven't found anything regarding ipv6. Any idea what could be blocking my traffic here?

I did a tracerout6:

```
sudo tcptraceroute6 -m 60 2a03:4000:66:cbd::1 22 
traceroute to 2a03:4000:66:cbd::1 (2a03:4000:66:cbd::1) from 2508:ed:4210:3109:9b92:89d:74db:ad8b, port 22, from port 16068, 60 hops max, 60 bytes packets
 1  abc.dip0.t-ipconnect.de (2003:af:4123:3109:1213:51ff:fecf:b5a8)  0.588 ms  0.375 ms  0.383 ms 
 2  2003:0:8004:5800::1 (2003:0:8004:5800::1)  10.816 ms  9.000 ms  8.563 ms 
 3  * * *         
 4  2003:0:1304:8032::1 (2003:0:1304:8032::1)  17.546 ms  63.950 ms  18.037 ms 
 5  2a00:11c0:47:1:47::140 (2a00:11c0:47:1:47::140)  20.733 ms  21.004 ms  20.215 ms 
 6  2a00:11c0:47:3::fb (2a00:11c0:47:3::fb)  21.080 ms  21.066 ms  21.206 ms 
 7  * * *         
 8  * * 2a03:4000:ff00:4::2 (2a03:4000:ff00:4::2)  2024.167 ms !H
```

Comment: Run `tcptraceroute` against port 22 and see how far you get.

Comment: See my updated post :). If I interpret it correctly it does not go through

Comment: Probably good to start with an output of `ip6tables -nvL`?

Comment: It goes through and for some reason, 2a03:4000:ff00:4::2, owned by netcup GmbH, are not passing the traffic through, probably because the host does not exist, as referenced by the `!H`. Nor does it exist from where I am. Perhaps you have the wrong IPv6 address.